# While(file_object) is an causing infinite loop

Tags: c++

This seems rather strange. I have a snippet of code that is as follows:

```
List(const char* fn) {
    std::ifstream file(fn);

    if (!file){
        throw std::string("*** Failed to open file ") + std::string(fn) + std::string(" ***");
    }
    while (file) {
        T e;
        if (e.load(file)){
            list.push_back(*new T(e));
        }
    }
}
```

With other people, it seems to run through the whole file just fine. But for me, I'm stuck in an infinite loop on my machine.

OS X - g++ 4.2

I have no clue as to why there is a difference of function here.

Here is the infinite loop:

```
while (file) {
    T e;
    if (e.load(file)){
        list.push_back(*new T(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `e.load(file)` is leaving the file in a valid state each time, when you expect it to leave it with `eof` or some other condition at the end of the file. I can't guess what it might be doing though.

Comment: T is a template variable, sorry. Yeah I would assume so, but it seems odd that it fails on my machine in particular.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper: I don't want to know that it is a template variable. I want to know what `T::load` does. Please show us your [minimal testcase](http://sscce.org), with which you've been debugging so far before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(file)` will return true as long as the file is left in a valid state.

You haven't told us what a `T` is or what its `load` method does, so we can't really give you much more info than that. You need to make sure that the `load` method either closes the file descriptor, or leaves it in `eof` state or something else like that.

Comment: It's not really the file descriptor you are talking about.

Comment: The problem was indeed in the load() function. It was leaving the file in a valid state -_-. Thank you so much my good sir!